# Kotlin aggregation function

Tags: list, kotlin

I need to write somehow a function, that aggregates results in a list.
I'm working with an Order dto (java class)

```
public class Order {
    private Long orderId;
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

I have two APIs, the one that return orders and the other one that returns suborders. So i retrieve all orders and get all suborders in a loop by predefined ids:

```
// for example i have a predefined list of order id's
List<Long> orderIds = listOf(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)

val allOrders = orderIds.map {
    // at first i retrieve an order
    val order = orderService.getOrderById(it.orderId)
    // then i get a list of suborders
    val suborders = suborderService.getSubordersByOrderId(it.orderId)
    // ?
}
```

How can i combine `order` (Order) and `suborders` (List) to a list of Order and then all the elements of nested list into a single list?

Comment: Combining into same list? or pairs?

Comment: Are suborders also of the type `Order`?

Comment: @Animesh Sahu, it's all about combining  an Order and List<Order> into a new List<Order>

Comment: @Egor, yeah same

Comment: `suborders + order`?

Comment: how can this be done outside .map { ... }?

Comment: @bajiepka13 what do you mean? you want to club all lists into one? Edit the question for what you expect it to be with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [flatMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) is what you want:

```kotlin
val allOrders: List<Order> = orderIds.flatMap {
    val order = orderService.getOrderById(it)
    val suborders = suborderService.getSubordersByOrderId(it)
    suborders + order
}
```

It flatten all the items of the returned list into one single list altogether.